# "Linked" still contains link which was introduced by a now deleted answer

Tags: bug, linked-questions

In [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345842/check-if-member-function-exists-and-is-not-inherited-for-sfinae) there was an answer which linked to this other question:

[Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now that this answer is deleted, the **"Linked"** section in my question still contains that link:

[image: linked questions]

Shouldn't this question be removed from the "Linked" section?

Comment: How long ago was the answer deleted?  I know the side bar is cached is not updated instantly.

Comment: @psubsee2003 approx. 24 hours ago

Comment: Huh? None of the questions that are linked on your question are deleted..

Comment: @JonClements I was referring to an answer of my question which contained a link to another question. THAT answer is now deleted

Comment: @m.s. ahh sorry... now I got you. Umm, I deleted the comment on the deleted answer that contained the link and it's gone straight-away from the sidebar... However, that does seem a little iffy to me - I'd have expected even if the comment wasn't deleted and the answer was it'd invalidate the link. Not sure if bug or by design though...

Comment: WOW, only one upvote? Was about posting the same.

Comment: I just noticed this happening on [list all local users using directory services](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8191696/150605) and [Get a list of members of a WinNT group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252882/150605).  The only link between the two questions is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191823/150605), which was deleted 8 years ago.  I don't know what the "correct" behavior should be, but I came here to find out and this seems to be the only question about the issue.